# How to sort a list in prolog

Tags: list, sorting, prolog

I would like to sort a list of movies in prolog. I have the following list of movies where the first number is the length of the movie, the second number is the age rating and the third is the rating of the movie 1-10:

```
db([
movie("District 9",[actor("Copley","Sharlto"),actor("James","David")],
[genre("Science-Fiction")],112,13,10).
movie("The Matrix",[actor("Reeves","Keanu")],[genre("Science- 
Fiction"),genre("Action")],136,13,10).
movie("Shutter Island",[actor("Dicaprio","Leonardo")],[genre("Drama")],136,16,8).
movie("Gladiator",[actor("Crowe","Russel")],[genre("Drama")],90,16,10).
movie("The Fault In Our Stars",[actor("Woodley","Shalaine")],[genre("Drama")],126,13,8).
]).
```

I would like to have a predicate like sortMoviesByRank(List,Sort) such that I get back a list of movies with the highest rank first to last.

Answer (score 0):

First, you must separate the elements of a list using commas.

```
db([movie("District 9",
          [actor("Copley","Sharlto"), actor("James","David")],
          [genre("Science-Fiction")], 
          112, 13, 10) ,                               % <== use comma!
    movie("The Matrix",[actor("Reeves","Keanu")],
          [genre("Science-Fiction"),genre("Action")],
          136,13,10) ,                                 % <== use comma!
    ...]).
```

Second, it's not clear which argument in a term `movie/6` term indicates the movie's rank. Thus, for simplicity, consider the following database where the elements are of the form `movie(Title, Rank)`:

```
simpler_db([
    movie("District 9", 5),
    movie("The Matrix", 1),
    movie("Shutter Island", 9),
    movie("Gladiator", 7),
    movie("The Fault In Our Stars", 8)]).
```

To obtain a list of movies with the highest rank first to last, you can use the predicate [sort/4](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=sort/4):

```
?- simpler_db(DB), sort(2, @>=, DB, List).

DB = [movie("District 9", 5), movie("The Matrix", 1), 
      movie("Shutter Island", 9), 
      movie("Gladiator", 7), 
      movie("The Fault In Our Stars", 8)],

List = [movie("Shutter Island", 9), 
        movie("The Fault In Our Stars", 8), 
        movie("Gladiator", 7), 
        movie("District 9", 5), 
        movie("The Matrix", 1)].
```

The goal `sort(2, @>=, DB, List)` sorts the elements of the list DB, in descending order (`@>=`) of argument `2` (thats is, `Rank`), keeping duplicates, producing  `List` as result.

**EDIT** To sort a list of terms, you need a goal of the form `sort(+Key, +Order, +List, -Sorted)`, where `Key` is the number of the term argument that must be used as the sort key. So, if movies are represented by terms of the form `movie(Title, Actors, Genre, Length, Age, Rating)`, and you want to sort by the argument `Rating` (which is the 6-th argument of the term representing movies), then you can ask:

```
?- db(DB), sort(6, @>=, DB, List).
```

Comment: For clarification, the third number represents the rank, the first number is the length, then the age rating and then the rating

Comment: @noobmaster69 Please, see section EDIT in my answer.